# rebind Angular Material autocomplete when the mat-options are toggled to be hidden or visible?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a table of 50 rows, where each row has a column with an autocomplete input. Each autocomplete has 350 options, which means I'm rendering 17k `mat-options`, which slows down the app and any interaction or click events on the autocomplete input.

The 50 rows and 350 options per autocomplete are mandatory requirements.

I'm testing out an improvement where I am currently showing the mat-options on focus and hiding them on blur:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    [(ngModel)]="element.assigned"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    (keyup.enter)="onAddAssignee($event, element)"
    (focus)="showAutocompleteOptions(element, true)"
    (blur)="onAddAssignee($event, element)"
  />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <div *ngIf="element.showAutocompleteOptions">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let assignee of assignees" [value]="assignee" (click)="onAddAssignee($event, element)">
        {{ assignee | truncate: 12 }}
      </mat-option>
    </div>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

showAutocompleteOptions(element: SomeObject, value: boolean): void {
  element.showAutocompleteOptions = value;
}

onAddAssignee(element: SomeObject): void {
  // adding some stuff
  this.showAutocompleteOptions(element, false);
}
```

This looks like it drastically speeds up the page. However, this breaks the autocomplete feature. I assume it's because the mat-options are removed from the DOM. How do I rebind it during on focus?

Or is there any other way I can resolve my original performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `observable` to handle this!

- define `input` field, that is linked with `FormControl`.
- track the `valueChanges` of the FormControl, it's already an `observable`.
- convert the `valueChanges` to a list of options.
- use `async` pipe for the `observable` options.

check this please:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbaaqlmqekm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts